# mvc : convert view model code to viewbag or viewdata

Tags: model-view-controller, viewmodel, viewbag

I am sending my table data to mvc web page through using view model. My code is shown below. Now I am given the task to send it through viewbag or viewdata. Any passionate programmer please edit the code to send it through viewbag or viedata and give a basic overview about how we use them i.e viewmodel or viebag differently.

Many thanks in advance.

```
  @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        }
        
        <h2>Index</h2>
        <div>
        <br /><br />
          <table style="width: 100%;">
             
          <tr>
            <th>UserID</th>
            <th>UserName</th>       
            <th>Adress</th>
          </tr>
          
             @foreach(var item in ViewData.Model)
              {
                  
           <tr>
            <td>@item.UserID</td>
            <td>@item.Username</td> 
            <td>@item.Adress</td>
          </tr>    
              }
    
            </table>
        </div>
    
    
    public class DetailController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                ViewData.Model = DetailModels.GetData();
                return View();
            }
    
        }
    
    
    
    
    public class DetailModels
        {
            public static List<User> GetData()
            {
                EmployeeEntities context = new EmployeeEntities();
                List<User> dt = context.Users.AsEnumerable().ToList();
                return dt;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include the library above

@using ProjectName.Models

```
@foreach (Users u in Model)
{
       <td>@u.UserID</td>
        <td>@u.Username</td> 
        <td>@u.Adress</td>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```
   public class DetailController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
          //  ViewData.Model = DetailModels.GetData();
              ViewData["DetailModels"] = DetailModels.GetData();
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**View :**

```
    @foreach(var item in ViewData["DetailModels"] as DetailModels)
          {
           <tr>
             <td>@item.UserID</td>
             <td>@item.Username</td> 
             <td>@item.Adress</td>
           </tr>    
          }
```